# Passing NULL to Overloading while checking Specificity in two Cases

Tags: java, overloading

In the First case, it returns the "String". But in Case 2, what happens when we pass NULL to Exceptions, ArithmeticExceptions and Object.

Case 1-

```
public class Question{
    public static void JavaHungry(String s)
    {
        System.out.println("String");
    }

    public static void JavaHungry(Object o)
    {
        System.out.println("Object");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JavaHungry(null);
    }
}
```

Case 2 -

```
public class Question3{
    public static void JavaHungry(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception");
    }

    public static void JavaHungry(Object o)
    {
        System.out.println("Object");
    }

    public static void JavaHungry(ArithmeticException ae)
    {
        System.out.println("AE");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JavaHungry(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because java uses the most specific type going from the child to the parent in class hierarchy

Comment: Thank You. Now I get it. @Toumash

Comment: just look at the duplicate question

Comment: Yes, it makes sense now.

Comment: @Toumash can you explain my edits ?

Comment: AE, because it's the child of Exception

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any docs for this hierarchy ? @Toumash ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5